# Is there a preferred charoset form?

Tags: halacha, food, passover-seder-hagada

I've seen charoset made like a paste and others made with loose, visible pieces of apples and nuts. Is there any halachic preference to either form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Gemara ([Pesachim 116a](http://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.116a.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) discusses the properties of charoset:

> רבי אלעזר בר' צדוק אומר מצוה וכו': מאי מצוה רבי לוי אומר זכר לתפוח ור'
>   יוחנן אומר זכר לטיט אמר אביי הלכך צריך לקהוייה וצריך לסמוכיה לקהוייה
>   זכר לתפוח וצריך לסמוכיה זכר לטיט תניא כוותיה דרבי יוחנן תבלין זכר לתבן
>   חרוסת זכר לטיט אמר רבי אלעזר בר' צדוק כך היו אומרים תגרי חרך שבירושלים
>   בואו וטלו לכם תבלין למצוה
>
> Rabbi Elazar son of Rabbi Tzadok says that 
>   [ḥaroset] is a mitzva. What is the nature of this
>   mitzva? Rabbi Levi says: It is in remembrance of
>   the apple. [The verse
>   states: “Who is this who comes up from the wilderness, reclining upon
>   her beloved? Under the apple tree I awakened you” (Song of Songs 8:5),
>   which is an allusion to the Jewish people leaving Egypt.] And Rabbi
>   Yoḥanan says: The ḥaroset is in remembrance of the mortar [used by the
>   Jews for their slave labor in Egypt]. Abaye said: Therefore, to fulfill
>   both opinions, one must prepare it tart and one must prepare it thick.
>   One must prepare it tart in remembrance of the apple, and one must
>   prepare it thick in remembrance of the mortar.

The Rama (Orach Chaim 473:5) cites this Gemara, as well as adding some additional customs:

> וחרוסת יעשה עב זכר לטיט ואחר כך נותנין בו מעט חומץ או יין אדום זכר לדם
>   (טור) ועושין החרוסת מפירות שנמשלו בהם ישראל (תוספות פרק ערבי פסחים)
>   כגון תפוחים תאנים אגוזים רימונים שקדים ונותנין עליו תבלין כגון קנמון
>   וזנגביל הדומים לתבן שהיו מגבלין בו הטיט (טור)

Both according to the Gemara and the Rama, the charoset should be thick. The Gemara and Rama do not mention how finely chopped the ingredients should be, however, [Rashi and Rashbam on the Gemara](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=116&format=pdf) say:

> וחרוסת שכותשים בו הדק זכר לטיט--charoset which is finely ground, in commemoration of the mortar.